# Compare rows in different column Teradata

Tags: teradata

I need compare value from 1 column with previous value from 2 column. For example, I have table:

`id | create_date | end_date
  1 | 2016-12-31  | 2017-01-25
  2 | 2017-01-26  | 2017-05-21
  3 | 2017-05-22  | 2017-08-26
  4 | 2017-09-01  | 2017-09-02`

I need to compare create_date for id = 2 with end_date for id = 1

and compare create_date for id = 3 with end_date for id = 2 etc.

**Result**: show me id which has create_date (id = n) <> end_date (id = n-1) + interval '1' day

Should I use lag() function? How I can compare it? Which function I should use and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teradata doesn't have lag/lead, but you can still get the same functionality:

```
select
id,
create_date,
end_date,
max(end_date) over (order by id between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end_date
...
qualify
create_date <> prev_end_date + INTERVAL '1' day;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I can't use analytical function in where. I just put it to subselect :) it works, thank you very much.

Comment: @monika01: No need for a Subselect, Teradata supports `QUALIFY` to filter on the result of an OLAP function.